# Possible To Install GRUB Alone On An Empty HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I have a machine with 3 disks: Win10 SSD(C:), WinStorage (E:) and an empty drive (D:).

I would like to keep my Win10 and WinStorage drives as is and on my empty E: drive, install the GRUB boot loader alone and without the presence of any other OS.

This is because I'd like to have my own compiled "kernel.bin" file within *boot/myos/kernel.bin*. I'd create a grub.cfg at /boot/grub/grub.cfg and add 2 boot options, one for my Win10, one for "myos". Is this a possibility or am I on a very wrong path here?

Thanks in advance for everyone's knowledge and time.

Answer (score 0):

Its not something I have tried, but I know its possible.  You can install GRUB to any disk, even external or removable drives.

Boot off of a Linux live USB and access a terminal with elevated privileges.  You can then use the `grub-install` program.  You would use a command like:

> grub-install /dev/sda

More information on `grub-install` can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html).